# ImageFlow display default width height

Tags: javascript, css, image

Has anyone here worked with http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/ it resizes my images, and I want them to look bigger, I've played with the settings...but....So can anyone help me? I want the imagesz to be displayed at 80-90% of the original width and height

Answer (score 2):

Try *increasing* the values of the following properties:

```
Name               Default value   Purpose
--------           -------------   -------
imageFocusM        1.0             Percent size of image in focus (1.0 = 100%)
imagesHeight       0.67            Percent height of main div container (.67 = 67%)
imagesM            1.0             Percent size of all images (not just in focus image)
percentLandscape   118             Scale of landscape images
percentOther       100             Scale of portrait or square images
```

Try:

1. imageFocusM = 1.8
2. imagesHeight = 1.2
3. imagesM = 1.8

Also, *very important*, don't forget about the height and width attributes on the img:

`<img src="images/image1.jpg" width="400" height="275" alt="Image 1" />`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the imagesM setting?
In your case:

```
var imgFlow = new ImageFlow();
imgFlow.init({ImageFlowID: 'your-flow-id-goes-here', aspectRatio: 1.0, imagesM: 0.8
```

That might work.

Answer (score 0):

I've used it once before and I think you need to adjust the "aspectRatio". It defaults to 1.964 try changing the value and see what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
imagesM:            0.6,            /* Multiplicator for all images in percent */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(window).load(function(){
     var reflection_2 = new ImageFlow();
     reflection_2.init({
          ImageFlowID: 'reflection_2',
          imageCursor: 'pointer',
          circular: true,
          reflections: false,
          buttons: true
     });
});
```

Load your ImageFlow plugin after window loads